# Phrase describing reading only fragments of a text

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase to describe reading only those fragments of a text/paper/book/etc. that I need to know i.e. not reading the whole thing but only a part of it that will be useful to me.

I've thought about "selective reading" but it looks like it has negative connotations and describes a lazy reader rather than one who chooses appropriate fragments wisely. What are your ideas?

Comment: I think you mean * skimming*,  otherwise it is called reading.

Comment: Doesn't skimming mean "fast reading"? The passages I've chosen I read very carefully.

Comment: Yes, there are some words like **peruse** and **pore (over)**,  or  **consult** as @Jacinto suggested, but after all they are sort of reading.

Comment: Actually skim means *to read something quickly in order to find a particular point or the main points*. For example: *I always skim the financial section of the newspaper.* (Oxford Dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ***consulting*** the text. From the [Oxford Learner´s Dictionaries:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/consult?q=consult)

> **3** [transitive] **consult something** to look in or at something to get information. *He consulted the manual*.

You can also [***look up***](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/look-up?q=look%20up) something in a dictionary or reference book.

Comment: I think it basically means *refer to* not reading.

Comment: @Afsane I suppose you could consult a picture book, but typically consulting a book will involve reading "fragments" of it. And it makes you sound purposeful and not lazy at all, which is one of the OP's concerns.